# Convert domain name to LDAP-style in .NET

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Is there a built-in C# function to convert a dot-style domain name (my.domain.name) to LDAP style domain components (dc=my,dc=domain,dc=component?

Comment: What about split the domain by "."?

Comment: @Daniel Don't do that.  It's not always working.  the DNS domain name may be different from the DN.  It's called disjoint namespace.  Check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731125(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string GetDomainDN(string domain)
{
    DirectoryContext context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, domain);
    Domain d = Domain.GetDomain(context);
    DirectoryEntry de = d.GetDirectoryEntry();
    return de.Properties["DistinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
}
```